# Data Entry form - only write a part of content to table

Tags: ms-access

hope you all are enjoying this frosty autumn.

I have a simple data entry form which shows a list of values taken from a query in a combo box. These values are combined like this value1 & " " & value2.

When I select one and save it to the table, the whole expression value1 & " " & value2 gets written to my field in the table but I only want value1 to be written.

I need the combined values in the combo box for usability reasons, it's a alphanumerical code and its human readable counterpart, in my datbase however I only need the code.

I've been trying to make a After Insert Macro Event that takes the newest row (Max(Id)?) and modifies the field in question with something like Left(Field, 7). Because value1 is always only 7 characters long.
Unfortunately I don't know if my condition works like this or if the Left function even can be used in access to modify a field's content. Needless to say, I couldn't make it work.

Any suggestions how to split up this combined value from the combo box so I can only save the first value to my table are highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify combobox query to select 2 columns: Value1 and value1 & " " & value2, leave bound column 1 (by default), change combobox property `Column Count` to 2 and hide first column: set `Column Width` to 0,2"
After this user will be able to select readable values, but only data from first column will be stored in database.

Comment: Thank you, sounds very promising. However I can not find the ColumnCount property, is it reachable through the GUI?